# Ejecutar comando SVN desde java a través de CMD

Tags: java, cmd, proceso, svn

Mi problema es que necesito hacer un programa que descargue una carpeta de un repositorio SVN (Subversion) para luego hacer unas comprobaciones con ese contenido.

El caso es que si en la consola `cmd` introduzco los comandos:

```
set ruta1="https://usuario-PC/svn/nombreRepositorio/nombreArchivo"
svn co %ruta1%
nombreArchivo\...
```

Lista todo el contenido del archivo o carpeta si la encuentra.

El caso es que a través del `cmd` encuentra el archivo y lo descarga además de mostrar escrito el contenido a través de la consola.

El problema viene cuando a través de Java intento ejecutar esto (que abra un `cmd` y ejecute el comando anterior, además de mostrarme el contenido a través de la consola de eclipse)

Este es mi código:

```
public class pruebacomando {

static String ruta = "https://usuario-PC/svn/nombreRepositorio/nombreArchivo";

    public static main(String[] args) {

        try {
              process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd / svn co " + "%" + ruta + "%")
              BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
              String line = null;
              while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                   System.out.println(line);
              }           

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }
}
```

Lo único que me muestra a través de la consola son las 2 líneas de texto que salen al abrir la consola `cmd`. Por lo tanto supongo que no está ejecutando el comando.

Si alguien puede ayudarme le estaría muy agradecido.

Comment: Saca traza dentro del catch.

Comment: Perdón se me olvidó escribir lo del catch, el caso es que si borro del .exec lo de 'cmd / ' provoca el siguiente error: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "svn": CreateProcess error=2, El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario que ejecutes "cmd" esto seria para lanzar el interprete de comandos que ya esta proporcionado por el runtime.

Simplemente ejecuta  la acción

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("svn co " + ruta)
```

Tambien puedes ejecutar varias acciones como si fuera un fichero "bat". Por ejemplo te puedes situar en una carpeta del sistema antes de descargar el fichero.

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd " + rutaAbsolutaLocal);
p.waitFor();
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("svn co " + ruta)
```

Donde "ruta" es la ruta HTTP donde esta tu repositorio y "rutaAbsolutaLocal" es una ruta donde quieres que descargue el contenido.

A parte de todo esto mi recomendacion seria que usaras una libreria de java para el acceso a SVN en lugar de llamar al CMD de forma que tu aplicación funcione aunque no este el cliente de linea d comandos de svn y ademas sea independiente del sistema operativo.

Por ejemplo tienes las librerias de [SVNKit](https://svnkit.com/) que proporcionan una buena opción de integración y tienen bastante documentación y ejemplos